Ubuntu 24.04 won't resume after hibernation
I recently activated hibernation on my ubuntu 24.04 system following this guide (using Swap-File). I had some trouble at first but then it worked perfectly. After fiddling with some other things, i somehow changed something, that broke it again.
The current state is: after hibernating, it takes some time to shut my laptop off possibly saving the session to the Swap file. When i start it, it is doing a normal boot without restoring the session.
I checked the kernel parameters (/etc/default/grub):
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=b974dbad-93b0-478c-b5b1-6757c9adb9ab resume_offset=5638144"

and the size of my swapfile in comparison to my RAM size - 16G (output of swapon --show):
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swap.img file  16G 512K   -2

and both should be alright.
I've attached some relevant journal log entries here, let me know, if something important is missing.
At this point, i have tried so many things and still have no idea, what could be the problem.
Edit
maybe this log of sudo dmesg | grep -i PM:helps:
[    0.024968] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.024969] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
[    0.024970] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x37c4c000-0x37e2cfff]
[    0.024971] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x38da4000-0x38da4fff]
[    0.024972] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x3d3c9000-0x3dcc8fff]
[    0.024972] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x3fadf000-0x41b7efff]
[    0.024973] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x41b7f000-0x44b2efff]
[    0.024973] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x44b2f000-0x44bfefff]
[    0.024974] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x44c00000-0x48ffffff]
[    0.024975] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x49000000-0x491fffff]
[    0.024975] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x49200000-0x493fffff]
[    0.024975] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x49400000-0x49ffffff]
[    0.024976] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x4a000000-0x503fffff]
[    0.024976] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x50400000-0xfe00ffff]
[    0.024977] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe010000-0xfe010fff]
[    0.024977] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe011000-0xfed1ffff]
[    0.024977] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.024978] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xffffffff]
[    0.104365] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x41b7f000-0x44b2efff] (50003968 bytes)
[    0.105216] PM: RTC time: 21:19:57, date: 2024-07-11
[    0.233986] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    1.043440] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    1.238494] PM:   Magic number: 0:333:348
[    4.897574] PM: Image not found (code -16)

Maybe the last Line could explain something?

Sorry about that, it was my bad.  To undo that part all you should have to do is rerun that command and either comment out the lines with # in front of them, or delete all the lines that were added.  Again, I am sorry about that (this is what I get for being extremely tired), I was really after the point of trying to get the RESUME file created, and using a swap file is actually new to me since all the way up to 22.04 I have only used swap partitions as I am too afraid of the drive not remounting properly and losing my hibernated save in it.

Don't worry, it happens. I thought i had already deleted the entries, but turns out that the only way to delete them was to comment them out, deleting them did not remove them. So the current state is how it was when i initially wrote this question.

(I deleted some comments to prevent confusion)

Diagnostic procedure:
First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp

Then, do your problematic action. When your system is usable again,
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"

This will show you all the log messages since you set pin.tmp. Some messages relate to your problem.
The messages produced by journalctl start with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger for more details.

Thank you for your answer. I attached the relevant log for the current state. Hope that helps. I still have no idea how to fix it.
